# how to add new column with constant value in a text file

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a large text file with  several columns and want to add a new column (no matter where) with constant value of 10000
please help

Comment: please add some rows of your input file

Answer (score 8):

The following `awk` command will add a tab-delimited column at the end of each line with the value `10000`:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ $(NF+1) = 10000; print }' infile >outfile
```

The data is read from `infile` and is written to `outfile`.

Change `\t` to whatever delimiter you need to use.

There are countless other ways of doing the same thing, obviously.  With `sed`, for example:

```
sed 's/$/,10000/' infile >outfile
```

This uses a comma as delimiter and simply substitutes in the string `,10000` at the end of each line.

Comment: I try this but it doesn't add the value on the same line ...it goes to the next row and the same for next line

Comment: @linux1 Is your text file a DOS text file (created on a Windows system)?

Answer (score 1):

starting in example from a tsv

```
id  name
1   a
2   b
```

using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

```
mlr --nidx --fs "\t" put -S '$yourfield="10000"' input.tsv >output.tsv
```

gives you

```
id      name    yourfield
1       a       10000
2       b       10000
```

Change \t to whatever delimiter you need to use.